# keras always return same values in a Human horses CNN model example

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a CNN model with Keras for Human vs Horses dataset to predict some images.

with following codes I build the model and save in a file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

training_dir = 'horse-or-human/training'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range= 0.2,
    height_shift_range= 0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range= 0.2,
    horizontal_flip= True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(training_dir , target_size=(300,300) , class_mode='binary')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16 , (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu , input_shape = (300,300,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32 , (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64 , (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512 ,activation=tf.nn.relu ),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = tf.nn.sigmoid)   
])

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.001) , metrics=['accuracy'] , loss='binary_crossentropy' )

validation_dir = 'horse-or-human/validation'

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir ,
    target_size=(300,300) ,
    class_mode='binary'
)

model.fit(train_generator , epochs= 15 ,validation_data=validation_generator)

model.save('human-horses-model.h5')
```

And this part of my code that using that model to predict s specific image :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from ipyfilechooser import FileChooser
import keras.utils as image
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('human-horses-model.h5')

fc = FileChooser()
display(fc)

img = image.load_img(fc.selected , target_size=(300,300))


img = image.img_to_array(img)
img /= 255.

img = np.expand_dims(img , axis=0)

output = model.predict(img)

if output[0]> 0.5 :
    print('selected Image is a Human')
else :
    print('selected Image is a Horses')
```

And following is output of each epochs:

```
Found 256 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/15
33/33 [==============================] - 83s 2s/step - loss: 0.7800 - accuracy: 0.5686 - val_loss: 0.6024 - val_accuracy: 0.5859
Epoch 2/15
33/33 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.6430 - accuracy: 0.6777 - val_loss: 0.8060 - val_accuracy: 0.5586
Epoch 3/15
33/33 [==============================] - 77s 2s/step - loss: 0.5252 - accuracy: 0.7595 - val_loss: 0.7498 - val_accuracy: 0.6875
Epoch 4/15
33/33 [==============================] - 79s 2s/step - loss: 0.4754 - accuracy: 0.7731 - val_loss: 1.7478 - val_accuracy: 0.5938
Epoch 5/15
33/33 [==============================] - 77s 2s/step - loss: 0.3966 - accuracy: 0.8130 - val_loss: 2.0004 - val_accuracy: 0.5234
Epoch 6/15
33/33 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.4196 - accuracy: 0.8442 - val_loss: 0.3918 - val_accuracy: 0.8281
Epoch 7/15
33/33 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.2859 - accuracy: 0.8802 - val_loss: 1.6727 - val_accuracy: 0.6680
Epoch 8/15
33/33 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.2489 - accuracy: 0.8929 - val_loss: 3.1737 - val_accuracy: 0.6484
Epoch 9/15
33/33 [==============================] - 76s 2s/step - loss: 0.2829 - accuracy: 0.8948 - val_loss: 1.8389 - val_accuracy: 0.7109
Epoch 10/15
33/33 [==============================] - 76s 2s/step - loss: 0.2140 - accuracy: 0.9250 - val_loss: 1.8419 - val_accuracy: 0.7930
Epoch 11/15
33/33 [==============================] - 73s 2s/step - loss: 0.2341 - accuracy: 0.9299 - val_loss: 1.5261 - val_accuracy: 0.6914
Epoch 12/15
33/33 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.1576 - accuracy: 0.9464 - val_loss: 0.9359 - val_accuracy: 0.8398
Epoch 13/15
33/33 [==============================] - 75s 2s/step - loss: 0.2002 - accuracy: 0.9250 - val_loss: 1.9854 - val_accuracy: 0.7344
Epoch 14/15
33/33 [==============================] - 79s 2s/step - loss: 0.1854 - accuracy: 0.9406 - val_loss: 0.7637 - val_accuracy: 0.8164
Epoch 15/15
33/33 [==============================] - 80s 2s/step - loss: 0.1160 - accuracy: 0.9611 - val_loss: 1.6901 - val_accuracy: 0.7656
```

My model always return 1 or a number very near to 1 that show all images are **Human** while in real that are Horse.

I searched a lot but did not find the answer!

Can anyone help me to find and solve the problem.

Comment: Could you share the loss-epoch variations for training and validation datasets?

Comment: @learner, I added what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `class_mode='sparse'` as you are using the image dataset and Adam optimzer for better results or change the kernel size to `(7,7)` or `(5,5)` to convolve the large image dataset efficiently.

(I have replicated the same code and attached the [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/081a31b3dda57dee6a9b79a64bbc93eb/74993119.ipynb) for your reference which predicts the expected result as you can see in the image below)

You can also try using [Pretrained model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#create_the_base_model_from_the_pre-trained_convnets) or [Strategies to prevent overfitting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#strategies_to_prevent_overfitting) for fine tune the model performance.

[image]